# How LiveData encapsulation works in AndroidStudio and Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, encapsulation

I am working on a project and I have ViewModel and using LiveData with encapsulation.

```
private val _counter = MutableLiveData<Int>()
val counter: LiveData<Int>
    get() = _counter
```

On activity side I observe counter from ViewModel.

```
viewModel.counter.observe(this, Observer {
    binding.clickCounterText.text = it.toString()
})
```

In ViewModel I only work with _counter, but counter observer knows that _counter have been changed?
HOW IT WORKS? How is counter changed when _counter is changed?

Please can someone explain it to me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `counter` is upcasting of `_counter` because of `_counter` is a `MutableLiveData` and `MutableLiveData` is a subclass of `LiveData`. When the Activity invoking the `counter` it actually gets the reference of `_counter`, so when the Activity observes the `counter` it is actually observing the `_counter`.

Answer (score 1):

> In ViewModel I only work with _counter, but counter observer knows that _counter have been changed? HOW IT WORKS? How is counter changed when _counter is changed?

`_counter` is initialized with `MutableLiveData<Int>()` whereas `counter` is **referring** to the instance of `_counter`.  Both are **referring** to the **same instance**, the only difference between the two is that `counter` is of type LiveData and `_counter` is **MutableLiveData**. Since the **reference/instance is same**, any change triggers **both**.